# Discrete Probability Distribution problem in java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve an introductory java problem and can't seem to figure out how to go about it. The objective is as follows:

Write a program DiscreteDistribution.java that takes an integer command-line argument m, followed by a sequence of positive integer command-line arguments a1,a2,…,an, and prints m random indices (separated by whitespace), choosing each index i with probability proportional to ai.

Sample input and output looks as such:

```
> ~/Desktop/arrays> java DiscreteDistribution 25 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 2 4 4 5 5
> 4 3 4 3 1 5 2 4 2 6 1 3 6 2 3 2 4 1 4
```

My implementation thus far is as follows:

```
public class DiscreteDistribution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = args.length;
        int[] freq = new int [n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            freq[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < freq.length;i++) {
            total += freq[i];
        }

        int r = (int) (total * Math.random());
        int sum = 0;
        int event = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n && sum <= r; i++) {
            sum += freq[i];
            event = i;
        }
        System.out.print(event);

    }
}
```

Further text from the problem suggests the following:

Define the cumulative sums Si=a1+a2+…+ai and S0=0.
Pick a random integer r uniformly between 0 and Sn−1.
Find the unique index i between 1 and n such that Si−1≤r

I believe I have appropriately defined cumulative sum in the total variable and picked the random integer r as well. However, I am unable to figure out how I can find the unique index.

Comment: Now what is your question? Please specify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to get a random sample of *m* indices without repetitions is to generate a sequence, shuffle it, and take the first *m* items.

```java
// Produce a sequence.
List<Integer> allIndices = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i += 1) allIndices.add(i);

// Shuffle the sequence in place.
Collection.shuffle(allIndices);

// Take a sublist of m elements, and use it.
List<Integer> indices = allIndices.subList(0, m - 1);
for (Integer ix : indices) {
  // Here ix will be a unique random index into freq, use it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DiscreteDistribution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = args.length;
        int [] a = new int [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        int [] s = new int [n];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            s[0] = 0;
            s[i] = s[i-1] + a[i];
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < a[0]; m++) {
            int index = 1;
            int r = (int) (s[n-1] * Math.random());
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (s[i-1] <= r && r < s[i])
                    index = i;
            }
            System.out.print(index + " ");
        }
    }
}
```